# (Node.js) How to save a user's shopping cart in express session?

Tags: node.js, express, session, cart

I'm trying to save the contents of a cart in express session.

````
```app.post('/api/cart', (req, res) => {
        var cart = req.body;
        req.session.cart = cart;
        req.session.save = (err) => {
        console.log(req.session.cart);
          if(err){
            throw err;
          }
          res.json(req.session.cart);```
````

For some reason.... this doesn't seem to be doing what I expect it to do? I can't get the log of session.cart after session.save. 
If I console log right before the session.save, I get this -

````
```[ { _id: '5b62566df354c821c87bd354',
[0]     title: 'stuff',
[0]     description: 'more stuff',
[0]     quantity: 2,
[0]     price: 2,
[0]     _merchant: '5b5f41e419c12630807979ec',
[0]     __v: 0 } ]```
````

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
app.post('/api/cart', (req, res) => { 
var cart = req.body; 
req.session.cart = cart; 
req.session.save(err, sessionCart) =>{ 
console.log(sessionCart); 
if(err){ throw err; }       
res.json(req.session.cart);
```

Hope this solves your problem.